# i want to send multiple checkbox data coming from DB to spring controller using js and ajex call

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

i want to send multiple selected  checkbox data(Id) to spring controller using js, ajex call and getting checkbox by class name "checkk" but whenever i press the submit button nothing happen. Here is my js and ajex code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submitdata').click(function() {
    getValueUsingClass();
});
});

function getValueUsingClass(){
var chkArray = [];
    $('.checkk:checked').each(function() {
    chkArray.push($(this).val());
});


$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '/spring-demo/channel/getBouquetsByChannelCode',
    cache: false,       

    data:'data=' + checkboxValues,
    success: function(){
        var selected;
        selected = chkArray.join(',') ;

        if(selected.length > 0){
            alert("You have selected " + selected); 
        }else{
            alert("Please at least check one of the checkbox"); 
        }
    },

    error: function(){                      
        alert('Error while request..');
    }
  });   
  }
```

And here is jsp code:

```
<div>
<table class="table table-bordered  " id="tablee">
<tbody>
<c:forEach var="ch" items="${Channels}" varStatus="status">
<tr><td id="check"><input type=checkbox name=channelCode 
class="checkk" value="${ch.channelCode}"></td>
<td>${ch.channelname}</td>
<td>${ch.price}&#x20b9;</td>
<td>${ch.languageSupported }</td>
<td>${ch.category}</td>
</c:forEach> 
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-md  btn-block " 
value="Check Out" id="submitdata" />
</div>
```

Here is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getBouquetsByChannelCode", method = 
RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getBouquets(@RequestParam("channelCode") String[] 
channelCode) {
List<Channel> channels = 
channelService.findBouquetByChannelCode(channelCode);
return new ModelAndView();
}
```

Please correct me how to do this.

Comment: You `ajax` code is not inside your `submit` code.

Comment: You have not attached channelCode to your mapping URL

Comment: i use Ajax code in separate file and import in jsp file@Scary,                             
can you please tell me how to attach channelCode in url mapping@Dinesh